# Gerrit Creating dependency across folders

Tags: git, gerrit

I have two folders like `git/Mycode/` and `git/MyDoc`.

Now I want to create dependency something like anytime you change anything in `MyCode` folder, you will have to mandatory make changes in `MyDoc`.

If `MyDoc` is not updated, code merge is not allowed.
Is that possible in GIT or any plugin available to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit is not strong on dependencies between repositories, and what you want sounds like something an IDE or tool-suite should be responsible for enforcing.

Gerrit is a code-review tool, not a process-management one. It sees each project as an independent repository.

And such a constraint is easy to bypass anyway for a developer who wants to game the system.

- How do you know the changes to the documentation match (or are even related to) the changes in the code?
- Do all code changes require documentation changes?
- And vice-versa

The best approach for this is to have the docs embedded in the code, then your reviewers can put a -2 on any code change which does not update the documentation as they will appear in the same commit. More importantly, the docs travel with the code when the repository is cloned or copied.